# ASP.NET MVC Dropdown List won't populate Results

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

Ok so I've spent a lot of time trying to figure out how to do a drop down for filters. Right now I have two filters as a textbox but I want a dropdown list instead as I would be adding few more filters.

This is my index page:

### Task List

```
<ul>
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Task"))
   {%>
    <fieldset> 
        <legend>Filters</legend> 
        Date Range: From
        <%: Html.TextBox("StartDT") %> 
        To
        <%: Html.TextBox("EndDT") %> <br />
        <%: Html.DropDownList("ClientName", "PhysicianName") %> 

    <input type="submit" name="Filter" value="Filter" /> 
    <input type="submit" name="ClearFilter" value="Clear Filter" /> 
    </fieldset> 
<% } %>
</ul>
```

This is the change I made in my Model:

```
    public class FilterViewModel
    {
        public PapClientProfile Client { get; set; }
        public PapStaff Physician { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ClientName { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PhysicianName { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the change I made in:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ViewResult Edit()
    {
        var model = new FilterViewModel { PossibleValues = PapClientProfile("ClientName"), PapStaff ("PhysicianName") };
    }
```

But I'm not able to populate any dropdown values. Can anybody please help?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    var model = new FilterViewModel 
    { 
        PossibleValues = new[]
        {
            new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "value 1" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "value 2" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "value 3" },
        }
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and then in your strongly typed view:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.Physician.PhysicianName, 
    new SelectList(Model.PossibleValues, "Value", "Text")
) %>
```

Comment: It does not recognize 'FilterViewModel'. When I add a new method with:

public class FilterViewModel
{
}

It gives an error with 'PossibleValues'

Comment: Where is `FilterViewModel` not recognized? Why are you adding methods to your view model? Is your view strongly typed to `FilterViewModel`?

Comment: Thanks for replying.

FilterViewModel is not recognized in the controller. Adding a method to get FilterViewModel to be recognized. Yes it is a strongly typed view. 

Can I please email you my project? I really need help with this dropdownlist. Thanks

Comment: @Mel, yes you can send me your project. But please narrow it down as much as possible. Don't expect me setting up databases and things like this in order to run it.

Comment: Nothing needs to be set up. Everything is set up. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your classes PapClientProfile and PapStaff, so I substituted them with simple string types. 
Assuming your ViewModel is defined like so:

```
 
    public class FilterViewModel
    {
        public string ClientName { get; set; }
        public string PhysicianName { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable ClientNames { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable PhysicianNames { get; set; }
    }
```

You will then have TWO lists available in the view. One containing ClientNames and 
one containing PhysicianNames. I'll assume this is correct for you?

Your controller code is like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    var model = new FilterViewModel 
    { 
        Client = "ClientID-2",
        Physician = "",

        ClientName = new[]
        {
            new SelectListItem { Value = "ClientID-1", Text = "Client Name 1" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "ClientID-2", Text = "Client Name 2" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "ClientID-3", Text = "Client Name 3" },
        },

        PhysicianName = new[]
        {
            new SelectListItem { Value = "PhysicianID-1", Text = "Physician Name 1" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "PhysicianID-2", Text = "Physician Name 2" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "PhysicianID-3", Text = "Physician Name 3" },
        }

   };
    return View(model);
}
```

If your view is strongly typed to get your FilterViewMode as model you can use the following code to display a dropdown list:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.ClientName, 
    new SelectList(Model.ClientNames, "Value", "Text")
) %>
<br/>
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.PhysicianName, 
    new SelectList(Model.PhysicianNames, "Value", "Text")
) %>
```

Personally I like to create the SelectLists in the controller, but it should work either way.